# Mouse been going crazy since 14.04 . Is there a fix?

Tags: 14.04, 15.10, mouse, bug-reporting

No matter what answer I've tried, if I've used the touchpad or a wireless mouse, my cursor will occasionally go wild. I've noticed it starts this behavior after long periods of use and continues untill the next day. Is this a bug? Is there another solution to this problem?
I'm currently using ubuntu 15.10

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: This sounds like maybe an issue with the touchpad, or maybe where your palms are resting on the touchpad. I presume this is a laptop with touchpad? I think there is an option to disable touchpad while typing, which might help.

Comment: It happens when I use the mouse also

Comment: Using the mouse does not disable the touchpad, though. It is simply an additional input device.

Comment: I understand this issue sounds weird, but I just started experiencing exactly the same. My cursor suddenly got a life of its own on my 16.04 installation on a Lenovo T460s. I have been using this laptop for over a year, have not changed any settings in the past month and today suddenly: erratic mouse behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1619040) topic a probable solution is proposed: install **gpointing-device-settings**, then uncheck the two boxes under System>Mouse for touchpad and run the app.